# Is it possible to determine the initial TTL of a volatile key?

Tags: redis

In a key-value persistance api I'm porting to Redis, I'm trying to implement a function that updates the time to live for a key. The original code stores ttl as a timestamp and # of minutes; the ttl is updated by writing a new timestamp (the key expires after timestamp + delta).

I've noticed that Redis provides a `TTL` command, but that only provides the time remaining.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to retrieve the original TTL from Redis (set with `EXPIRE`, etc), or if I need to add a TTL meta field to the values I'm storing (like the original code does).

Edit:
I'm using Redis Server v2.4.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, Redis stores converts the TTL into a unix timestamp. See [function expireGenericCommand in db.c](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/db.c#L513). So, Redis cannot return the TTL you specified, simply because it does not store it in that format.

You will need to add a TTL meta field if it is important for your application.

Comment: Thanks, there's no higher authority than the source!